# svn - deleted file still appears as unversioned (with a + sign) and updating it doesn't restore the file

Tags: svn

When I do `svn st`, I get a line like this :

```
 !  +    src/com/some_file.java
```

I have deleted it from the file system, but it still shows up. I understand that ! stands for unversioned files, but what does `+` stand for ?

The file is present in the repository. If I do `svn up`, the file should have been restored from the repository, but nothing happens. Due to this, during server startup, this file can't be found, and an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

"!" means "missing", not "unversioned" ("?" means "unversioned"). This happens if you delete a file using filesystem means, but not `svn rm`.

To restore the file run `svn revert src/com/some_file.java`

Comment: Yeah.. but I deleted all .svn-base and .svn-revert files associated with it.. !! I thought that they were holding erroneous information about the file

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform "svn rm" in order to remove a file from the repository (and not only from your local copy). If it is unversioned, it shouldn't be in the repository and viceversa. Maybe it was an added file not committed yet. "[Svn rm](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html)" should remove it from the list of file to be added.

Comment: The file is in the central repository... I don't know how its showing it as unversioned.. There are no local changes.. so I want to delete my local copy and get a fresh one from the repository..

Comment: try svn rm anyway... what happens?

Comment: it gets a "D" in front of it.. and it still doesn't get updated

Comment: you had to commit after the "svn rm". Anyway, do you want the file to disappear correctly, or rather do you want to have it back? - anyway if it's the case of maxim1000 answer, "svn revert" is for you

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: you told SVN that you add this file (directly or through some plug-in) and then deleted the file from disk.

In this case SVN remembered that the file was added, but cannot find it on disk.

If the guess is correct you should revert adding operation. For command-line it's "svn revert "

Comment: Yeah.. but I deleted all .svn-base and .svn-revert files associated with it.. !! I thought that they were holding erroneous information about the file